# Layout an Xml to my android App

Tags: java, android, xml

Good morning ! So I have this

MainActivity.java

```
import......

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  getXmlTask task = new getXmlTask(textview1 , "http://www.3pi.tf/test.xml");
  task.execute(); 
 }
}
```

and there is my getXmlTask.java

```
import....etc

public class getXmlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    private static final String TAG2 = null;

    private WeakReference<TextView> textViewReference;
    private String url;

    public void GetXmlTask(TextView textView, String url) {
        this.textViewReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(textView);
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.v(TAG2, "testnew");
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        Log.v(TAG2, "testurl");
        HttpResponse rp = null;
        try {
            rp = hc.execute(post);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v(TAG2, "testpost");

        if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            try {
                return EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Error";
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       
        TextView textView = textViewReference.get();
        if(textView != null) {
            textView.setText(result);
        }       
    }

}
```

No error on getXmlTask.java but i have this error on line

```
getXmlTask task = new getXmlTask(textview1 , "http://www.3pi.tf/test.xml");
```

It says "textview1 cannot be resolved to a variable"... but I "+id" on my mainlayout.xml.. 
Sorry i just begin on android development and sorry again for my english ^^

Comment: can i know what do you want to do with this

Comment: please follow the language conversions of Java. User Uppercase for class names and please dont name a class after a method :-)

Comment: I just want to layout/get this page http://3pi.tf/test.xml on my android app..

Comment: Is textview1 your ID? I mean '@+id/textview1'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`textview1` should be a variable in your `MainActivity` like

```
TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

and then pass `textview1` to your `getXmlTask`